# Removing old content databases cleanly

Tags: development, content-database

I have created and deleted a web application without specifying to remove the content database.

What is the cleanest way for me to delete the content database?

Comment: Did you delete web app Central Admin?

Comment: No I was using powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your content database is not listed in central administration in Manage content databases under Application Management section. When you're sure that your database is not listed there, you can remove your database from SQL server. As far as I know, you have to do it manually by connecting with SQL Management Studio.